# Firebase Dynamic links - when clicked not working in iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, safari, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

Im using firebase dynamic link to open the mobile application (If already installed) or to redirect user to Playstore or app store.

In iOS mobile , I pasted the link in notes / messaging apps and while clicking the link it Opens the safari browser and it shows the Preview page. Upon clicking the "Open" button in preview page , it says "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid".

Can you please help me with this?

Note : In same iOS device , when I set the default browser to chrome and then clicking the Link opens the app correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally I am able to resolve the issue.**
The initial step is to create a universal link in Firebase console.
Once the universal link is created , we have to do following changes in XCode:

1. Enable associated domains under capablities
2. Include URL types
3. Must verify your Team ID that you would have provided in firebase console.

Once the universal link setup is completed in Xcode, we can do build and run and check the working of Universal link.

i.e. clicking the link should open the app (provided app is already installed).
and it should not open the safari browser.

If clicking the link opens safari browser , then there is a problem with the Universal link setup.

The below tutorial is very useful:

https://youtu.be/KLBjAg6HvG0